# Formulas to Switch Row and Column References in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have raw data that is arranged like this:

[image]

The top row is the trial number. Then the first entry in each row is an ID.

I'm trying to set up a template for this data. When this data is pasted in, I want it to be read by another sheet. This sheet will automatically transpose the data, so that it looks like this:

[image]

On this sheet, then, I've been trying to write a formula that will increment horizontally when dragged down vertically. When I copy the formula horizontally, I would need it to increase the row reference, not the column reference, so that it'll reproduce the end result in the screenshot above.

I've tried variations on a formula like

```
INDEX('Asset Returns'!$B$2:$Z$2,COLUMN()-1,ROW()-1)
```

but I haven't been able to get it working as described. Thanks in advance for any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is Paste Special, Transpose not working for you?

Comment: I would suggest paste-special transpose as well. It makes the most sense.

Comment: Unfortunately not as I would need the cell addresses as part of another formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I've understood, but if what you're doing is transposition, but wanting to do it via a common forumla in all the destination cells, you can do it using this:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN(A1),ROW(A1),1,1,"Asset Returns"))
```

This should be pasted into the A1 cell of your "transposed" sheet, or adjust the cell reference accordingly if that isn't where the data is.

Another option is:

```
=OFFSET('Asset Returns'!$A$1,COLUMN(A1)-1,ROW(A1)-1)
```

Comment: Actually I have a followup question if you don't mind. Do you have a suggestion for a non-volatile function that could do the same thing? This solution works, but across a large dataset it becomes extremely slow.

Comment: I've added a second option, which _may_ be more efficient. When dealing with large datasets in Excel, I've found the following help: (a) turn off automatic calculations if that's workable (use F9 to refresh calcs when necessary), (b) remove as many formulae as you can (copy and paste values), (c) get as much RAM in your PC as it will allow, (d) use Excel's built in functionality whenever possible ... it's almost certain to be more efficient than hand-cranked methods. In this case, that should push you in the direction of using the Copy&Paste-with-transpose if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you! I made those changes and it's much quicker now.